# Query data with NodeJS#find() function from a MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve data from a MongoDB with Node. Here is my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

module.exports.get = function (req, res) { 
    //console.log(req.params.id)
    //prints 1
    var query = {};
    query['id'] = req.params.id;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        db.collection('events')
            .find(query)
            .limit(1)
            .next( function (err, event) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send('Could not bring the resource requested!');
                }
                if (event) {
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    res.send(event);
                }
                else {
                    res.status(404).send('Can\'t find the resource you\'re looking for');
                }
                // db.close();
            });
    })
}
```

In my db, I have a document that has its own id field, different from _id.

Problem is with this line of code: `query['id'] = req.params.id;`
Using this, I get `event = null`.

But, when I change this to: `query['id'] = 1;`, I get the data that I'm looking for. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: @Alex Managed to solve the problem.  I have to use Number(req.params.id) beacause req.params.id is a String.

Comment: Great! You could add the answer yourself and then accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem. I was getting this because of `req.params.id` that is a String.

I used  `Number(req.params.id)` and it's working.